# Mandar dados de um csv para um array

Tags: vb.net

Necessito de mandar os dados que estao num ficheiro csv para dentro de um array.

Já tenho o importador do ficheiro csv e o mesmo é lido só falta é mandar os dados para o array.

------editado-------

Utilizando o **Infragistics.Documents.Excel** já tenho acesso ao documento csv, sendo que necessito agora de enviar os dados de cada linha para um array.

Comment: José, explique melhor sua dúvida, adicione mais detalhes, exemplos, ou até o que você já tem. Assim conseguirão te ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consegui resolver com

```
Dim iRow As Integer = 1
                Dim iCol As Integer = 0

                Dim valores As String



                While oWorksheet.Rows(iRow).Cells(iCol).Value IsNot Nothing
                    valores = oWorksheet.Rows(iRow).Cells(iCol).Value
                    iCol += 1
                End While
```

Answer (score 0):

Experimenta assim:

```
Dim arrName() As String
Dim arrValue() As String

Using ioReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("C:\test\test.csv")

    ioReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
    ioReader.SetDelimiters(",")

    While Not ioReader.EndOfData

        Dim arrCurrentRow As String() = ioReader.ReadFields()

        If arrName Is Nothing Then

            ReDim Preserve arrName(0)
            ReDim Preserve arrValue(0)

            arrName(0) = arrCurrentRow(0)
            arrValue(0) = arrCurrentRow(1)

        Else

            ReDim Preserve arrName(arrName.Length)
            ReDim Preserve arrValue(arrValue.Length)

            arrName((arrName.Length - 1)) = arrCurrentRow(0)
            arrValue((arrValue.Length - 1)) = arrCurrentRow(1)

        End If

    End While
```

Comment: Pedro não funcionou ...